# How to escape certain characters in java

Tags: java, regex, escaping

I need to escape characters like `^`, `.`, `[`, `]`, `+` and `\` (tabs and newlines won't be an issue), while leaving others like `*` and `?`.

EDIT = More specifically, I have a string with these characters, and I need to escape them so that they are not matched by regular expressions. I need to prepend `\` to each of these characters, but doing so individually would take 7 or 8 scans and I'd like to do it within just one pass (IE: anything that matches is prepended with `\`)

How do I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Isn't the escape character "\"?

Comment: Escape where? In a regular string? In a regex?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't specific enough. I just edited the question.

Comment: Better now :-). See the code snippet I posted below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Would this work?

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : myString.toCharArray())
{
    switch(c)
    {
        case '[':
        case ']':
        case '.':
        case '^':
        case '+':
        case '\\':
            sb.append('\\');
            // intended fall-through
        default:
            sb.append(c);
    }
}
String escaped = sb.toString();
```

Comment: The method getChars(char[], int) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments () ...

Comment: Yes, noticed after posting (didn't have a compiler at hand) and fixed already.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of this. It looks great!

I'm going to check it out later; I'll give you the best answer if it works.

Comment: @elite5472: Here's a link in case you want to play with it online: http://ideone.com/aZHKf

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that:  [Pattern.quote()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29)

It escapes anything that would be recognized as regex pattern language.

Comment: problem is that I need characters like * and ?, which must be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

To escape a String to be used as a literal in a regular expression you can use `Pattern.quote()`

or just surround the string with `\\Q` and `\\E`.

Answer (score 0):

The \Q and \E and `java.util.Pattern.quote()` are the same approach.

However, this approach only works for a subset of regex flavors.

Check out the following link and you'll see that 4 of 15 flavors support it. So you're better off using Grodriguez's approach if you need to execute your regex in anything other than Java, such as javascript (which uses ECMA).

http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html

Here is a one-liner that might work.

```
"text to escape".replaceAll("([\\\\\\[\\]\\.\\^\\+])","\\\\$1");
```

Answer (score -1):

You do this by prepending `\` to the character you want to escape.